# Request for Steam keys for free game - is this a scam?

Tags: steam

I recently converted [my own paid Steam game](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1342600/Oneons_Prisoners/) into a free game. Since then, I got two requests (one via Discord, and one via email) for a Steam key for the game.

Is this a scam, or harmful in any way (to me or to Steam)?

The only possibility I can think of is that giving a key to someone with an account without any paid games, legitimizes them (they look like a real/paying account, which unlocks ... something, I don't remember what).

The second request mentioned that "free-to-play games don't show up properly in the library," which seems like misinformation to me. I've played a number of free games on Steam, and never saw any issues with them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You should direct their inquiries to Steam Support.

Whatever issues they are having, you giving them a key isn't a solution. They need to contact support to resolve whatever they are experiencing.

In addition, your research shows there can be potential issues with giving them keys so there's no point in contributing to that.

Just like in Finance SE, you don't need to understand the scam; just avoid it.

Comment: Got this suggestion from someone else, too. Steam suggests ignoring them if I think they're scammers, and being careful with keys, which are very sensitive.